# UltiSnips: How to make placeholder optional

Tags: option-type, code-snippets, ultisnips

I have to create something that looks like this:

```latex
\begin{frame}[fragile]{frame title}
  lorem ipsum ...
\end{frame}
```

Note that the portion `[fragile]` is optional. That is, if I enter some text in the `$1` placeholder, it should include the brackets. If I don't enter text in the `$1` placeholder, I don't want the brackets at all.

I'm not sure how to make the `$1` placeholder optional. So far I've created this snippet, which does everything except the optional part.

```
snippet frame "frame environment" b
\begin{frame}[$1]{${2:frame title}}
  ${0:${VISUAL}}
\end{frame}
endsnippet
```

**How can I make an optional placeholder that disappears when no text is given?**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple snippet that I think will explain the optional placeholder:

```
snippet \dc "Document Class" b
\documentclass${1:[${2:options}]}{${3:class}}
$0
endsnippet
```

Here is how it works:

- Type `\dc` and press `<tab>`.
- The `\documentclass[options]{class}` text will appear with `[options]` highlighted.
- At this time you can either press `<backspace>` and delete the whole `[options]` part (including the square brackets) and press `<C-j>` (forward trigger keymap) to continue to the `{class}` placeholder and so on...
- Or you can press `<C-j>` and proceed to change the `[options]` placeholder inside the square brackets. Then press `<C-j>` again to jump to the `{class}` placeholder and so on.